# Dual Color Putty

Tags: putty, colors

How Can I / (can I even) allow for two color schemes in Putty? I want data received to be in one color, and transmitted data / commands be in a second color. Can I configure Putty to show data in multiple colors?

Thank you,

Michael

Comment: Unless you're using local echo, this can't work -- putty can't distinguish between remote output and remotely-echoed local input.

Comment: I am using local echo, but still have not discovered how to set typed text to one color, and leave received data a separate color.